# Whats the difference between DjangoModelPermissions and DjangoObjectPermissions

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Whats the difference between [DjangoModelPermissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissions) and [DjangoObjectPermissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangoobjectpermissions)?

I'm still learning Django and DRF and according to the docs, they seems to do exactly the same thing.

> **DjangoModelPermissions:**
>     This permission class ties into Django's standard django.contrib.auth model permissions.

> **DjangoObjectPermissions**
>    This permission class ties into Django's standard object permissions framework that allows per-object permissions on models

For the later, it seems like it has something to do with [Django’s permission framework foundation which has no implementation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#handling-object-permissions) and apparently, [django-guardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian) fills in this gap.

In Django admin, I'm able to assign a Model's CRUD permission to users and groups, so what does the later add?

I'm trying to wrap my head around this permission system. What are the differences and what should I know about them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`DjangoModelPermissions` is all about permissions to interact with a database table which are represented as models in code while `DjangoObjectPermissions` are permissions to interact with individual rows in the table which are model instances in code. 
Basically, the object permissions are granular permissions which give access to some rows in a table but can restrict access to other rows in the same table

Answer (score -1):

> DjangoModelPermissions

Simple explanation, **DjangoModelPermissions** deals with the table permission access which let's you dictate which table can be accessed by someone with certain permissions.

> DjangoObjectPermissions

**DjangoObjectPermissions** deals with the individual objects in your model per-object permission instead of the model. So it gives a very detailed access control. But it might not be applicable at all times.

Comment: How is this different from the original answer?